# Windows 10's search does not find one specific folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1038485/windows-10-search-indexing-does-not-find-my-files) is about Windows Search not finding any files.
Mine concerns only one folder.

There is a "To read" folder in my Documents, which is never found by Windows Search when I type "to read" (or any variation with a different case).
Its contents, however, are found correctly (it's a hierarchy of sub-folders and PDF files).

The folder is not excluded from indexing.
Its permissions look normal.
I have tried to re-build the index, without success.
I haven't tried to reset or reinstall Windows, since restoring my environment would be quite a hassle.

Why would this specific, seemingly normal folder be ignored by Windows 10's search function?

Comment: Does the folder appear when you use: `kind:=folder` in the **Explorer** Search bar?

Comment: @KeithMiller Yes, it does.

Comment: That's promising. `Shift+Right-clcik` in the _background_ of the "To Read" folder & select `Open PowerShell window here`. Then copy & paste & execute the following command. `gi $pwd | select name ,  Attributes, {$_.name.length} , @{n='Bytes';e={[Byte[]][Char[]]($_.name) -join '-'}} | fl`. Then edit your question to include the output from the command.